# Strong paramters and nested attributes/forms giving me grief

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms, strong-parameters

So I am having some problems with strong parameters and nested forms (suprise! Nobody's ever had that problem before lol) and I've been looking at several threads, trying different solutions but still can't get a nested attribute to work so I turn to you, fellow programmers. Firstly lets look at the code, shall we? If you find anything fishy, let me know!

Aventure.rb

```
class Adventure < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :photos
has_many :reservations
has_many :activity_dates
accepts_nested_attributes_for :activity_dates
...
end
```

Activity_date.rb

```
class ActivityDate < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :adventure
has_many   :time_slots
accepts_nested_attributes_for :time_slots
end
```

Timeslot.rb

```
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :activity_date
end
```

_form.hmtl.erb

```
 <%= form_for @adventure, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
 ...
 <%= f.fields_for :activity_dates, @adventure.activity_dates.new do |a| %>
    <%= a.date_field :date %>
    <%= a.hidden_field :adventure_id, value: @adventure.id %>                  
 <% end %>
```

adventure_controller.erb

```
  def adventure_params
   params.require(:adventure).permit(:activity_name,:description,:leader,
                                    :company_name,:adress,:max_perticipants,
                                    :price,:currency,{:activity_dates=>[:dates]})
  end
```

Right, so when I inspect the params like below I get these 
[hashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZkaF.png) (see img link):

```
     render json: { p: params.inspect, ad:adventure_params.inspect }
```

I have concluded that activity_dates shows up in params, but NOT in ad:adventure_params. Using params[:activity_dates] gives a ForbiddenAttributesError, which was expected. That's not a good way of going about it, as it is not permitted in the strong params. I would however like to get :activity_dates with it's attribute date, and later on even it's nested attribute for :timeslots. But no matter how many solutions I have looked at, I have not been getting the desired results. What am I doing wrong? Help me Obi-Wan, you are my only hope!

Comment: What hash do you get for params? Also what hash do you get for adventure_params?

Comment: [Params](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wZkaF.png), p is params ap is adventure_params :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the hash tags around the activity_dates: [:dates] part in your adventure_params method?

Answer (score 1):

For nested attributes you need to add '_attributes' to the end of field name when you are adding them to your strong parameters, so you need to permit `activity_dates` as `activity_dates_attributes` as follows:

```
params.require(:adventure).permit(:activity_dates_attributes=>[:dates])
```

or as follows with your other permitted parameters:

```
params.require(:adventure).permit(:activity_name,:description,:leader,
                                    :company_name,:adress,:max_perticipants,
                                    :price,:currency, :activity_dates_attributes=>[:dates])
```

For more information on whitelisting strong parameters here are some useful links here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/